# Scatter Plot with best fitted regression line and r square in python

Tags: pandas, scatter

I would like graph scatter plot of (X,Y)   and on the plot I would like to put equation of best fitted linear line and r^2  and if possible correlation btw x and y on the plot . Please help.
Thank you

```
 from pandas import DataFrame
 data = {'X':[2195,2886,2399,1929,2643,2986,2337,2837,2501,2290,1940,2488,2628,2527,2596,2551,2427,2412,2275,2578,2725,2734,2595,2370,1916,2226,2156,1965],
    'Y':[10539,20043,12702,8654,19092,16719,8189,18517,12265,7749,5835,7640,8722,12540,16974
        ,11614,7458,7896,7929,8820,8925,7993,8178,7258,5702,9240,9877,5338]}
    df = DataFrame(data, columns= ['X', 'Y'])
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe this achieves what you are looking for. I realized you may mean you want to display the r^2 and formula physically on the plot so I edited and included that.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats

data = {'X': [2195,2886,2399,1929,2643,2986,2337,2837,2501,2290,1940,2488,2628,2527,2596,2551,2427,2412,2275,2578,2725,2734,2595,2370,1916,2226,2156,1965], 'Y':[10539,20043,12702,8654,19092,16719,8189,18517,12265,7749,5835,7640,8722,12540,16974,11614,7458,7896,7929,8820,8925,7993,8178,7258,5702,9240,9877,5338]}

df = DataFrame(data, columns= ['X', 'Y'])

m, b, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(df['X'], df['Y'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['X'],df['Y'])
ax.plot(df['X'], m*df['X'] + b)
ax.annotate('r^2: ' + str("{:.2f}".format(r_value**2)), xy=(1950,19500))
ax.annotate('formula: ' + str("{:.2f}".format(m)) + 'x + ' + str("{:.2f}".format(b)), xy=(1950,18500))

fig.show()

print(r_value**2)
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcqrf.png)